# Why onTestStart and onTestResult reporter event handlers are not called

Tags: jestjs

I run Jest with a simple custom reporter. For now event handlers of this reporter merely write their name to console. In the course of test run, among the many event handlers (that are defined in [`Reporter` interface](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/12a983b57fcd6e26a845bc2b9fa0fd217b95e7aa/packages/jest-reporters/src/types.ts#L59)), the `onTestStart` and `onTestResult` are not called at all.

Find code here: https://github.com/zoltan-boros/dummy-jest-reporter

Is this due to some mistake in my code? Or, are these event handlers decommissioned, i.e. is `Reporter` interface out of sync with current behavior?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

onTestStart and onTestResult have the same usage as onTestFileStart and onTestFileResult. They will only be called if the onTestFile... method is not defined.

It seems to me that there is no method for a single test.